# Can't remove %PATH% variable?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, command-prompt

I'm using Windows 10.

I somehow added a variable to `%PATH%` in the command line (I don't remember how), and it now shows up when I type `echo %PATH%`. However, when I go to the GUI Environment Variables, that certain variable appears neither in the `Path` of "User variables for [my_username]" nor the `Path` of "System variables".

How do I find where I can edit `%PATH%` and remove the variables I need to remove?

Comment: If you didn't extended the variable in the system settings, just reboot your computer. Otherwise this may help: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows) (a thread with exhaustive explanation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most certainly used "set" to change a environment variable for the current cmd.exe. The change does only affect the currently running cmd.exe process.

see also: https://ss64.com/nt/set.html

Comment: That makes sense - I restarted the command prompt and it was gone.